# Parse error in pattern: receiveTab

Tags: haskell

I have been working on a Haskell project. After producing some lines of code, and when I tried to load the .hs file via ghci, I receive this message, which I do not seem to understand why does it even show.

```
type Tab = [String]

task :: Tab -> Tab
task t = 
    let (receiveTab t)      = a
        (receivePosition t) = b --receivePosition and nextPosition are not really relevant to the context of this question
    in nextPosition a b

receiveTab :: Tab -> Tab
receiveTab (h:t)
        | elem ' ' h = []
        | otherwise  = receiveTab t
```

After attempting to load my .hs file, I receive the message:

> task2.hs: Parse error in pattern: receiveTab

It might be a really simple mistake, but my brain can't process what's wrong there, and I can't really afford to just discard the code and start it all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean

```
let a = receiveTab t
    b = receivePosition t
```

Variables (or patterns in general) generally go to the left of the equals sign, values go to the right, as in most other languages.

Comment: Hey, I think that might actually be it. Thanks for pointing it out.